# Procedure or function Insert has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#

I try this code but not working properly (only first value add to database second value is not inserted) . Procedure or function Insert has too many arguments specified ,this is the displayed error

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgItems.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgItems.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewCellCollection c = dgItems.Rows[i].Cells;

        //dtl.DOC_TYPE = type;
        info1.DOC_NO = DOC_NO.Text;
        info1.ITEM_CODE = c["cCode"].Value.ToString();
        info1.ITEM_DESC_ENG = c["cName"].Value.ToString();
        info1.UOM = c["cUnit"].Value.ToString();
        info1.PRICE = Convert.ToDecimal(c["cPrice"].Value.ToString());
        info1.QUANTITY = Convert.ToInt32(c["cQty"].Value.ToString());
        info1.ITEM_DISCOUNT = Convert.ToDecimal(c["cDisc"].Value.ToString());
        info1.DISC_TYPE = c["DiscTypes"].Value.ToString();
        info1.DISC_VALUE = c["DiscValues"].Value.ToString();
        info1.SERIALNO = c["SerialNos"].Value.ToString();
        info1.BRANCH = lg.Branch;
        if (hasTax)
        {
            info1.ITEM_TAX_PER = Convert.ToDecimal(c["cTaxPer"].Value.ToString());
            info1.ITEM_TAX = Convert.ToDecimal(c["cTaxAmt"].Value.ToString());
        }
        if (hasBatch)
        {

            info1.BATCH = c["cBatch"].Value.ToString();
            info1.EXPIRY_DATE = DateTime.ParseExact(c["cExpDate"].Value.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        }
        //cmd.CommandText += " UNION ALL ";
        dtl.Insertdtl_Meth(info1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably in the `Insertdtl_Meth` method. Are you resetting the parameters each call, or are they accumulating?

Comment: Where do you initialize `info1` ? This sample is not complete.

Comment: a [mcve] would be great

Comment: If you put a breakline on the line dtl.Insertdtl_Meth(info1); does it get executed more than once?

Comment: error:Procedure or function Sp_Sale_Dtl_Insert has too many arguments specified.,   Sp_Sale_Dtl_Insert means storedprocedure name

Comment: can you show the code for "Insertdtl_Meth"?

Answer (score 0):

Check the number of parameters your stored procedure **Sp_Sale_Dtl_Insert** requires and number of parameters being passed to it.

Chances are in the first iteration hasTax and hasBatch both are false or at least one is false and the number of parameters being passed matches what is required by the stored procedure.

In the second iteration most likely (if in the first iteration both were false) at least one is true causing no. of parameters being generated for the stored procedure to be more than what it requires or if in the first iteration one was true then in the second iteration both **hasTax** and **hasBatch** is true and thus again generating more no. of parameters than required.

Also please check **dtl.Insertdtl_Meth(info1);** method for how it is generating the parameters and passing it to the stored procedure.

Comment: hasTax and hasBatch are removed from code,not working for remaining code

Comment: Do you have access to the code inside dtl.Insertdtl_Meth(info1); ? The code inside must be creating parameters and passing to the stored procedure. Check how many parameters it creates and how many does your stored procedure actually expect.

Comment: Yes i'll access code from dtl.Insertdtl_Meth(info1) ,code is running using break then the dtl.Insertdtl_Meth(info1) is correct working ,parameters are passed is correct,the first iteration is correct and proerly insert into database ,for second iteration the error will displayed

Comment: Please check if command object (something like SqlCommand) is created inside the method and global command object is not used. Chances are if global command object (one declared outside Insertdtl_Meth function) is used and is not being initialized again parameters are getting added to it and number of parameters increasing in the second iteration itself (provided commands parameter collection is not cleared). Also check if command is a local variable then it is not using global parameter collection. Please paste code of the Insertdtl_Meth function. It would help track it down faster.